# Compare lists of column rows and using filters on them in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
sales = [(3588, [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,38,9,2,18,5]),
         (3588, [2,5,7], [1,2,4,8,14]),
         (3588, [3,10,13], [1,3,4,6,12]),
         (3588, [4,5,61], [1,2,3,4,11,5]),
         (3590, [3,5,6,1,21], [3,10,13]),
         (3590, [8,1,2,4,6,9], [2,5,7]),
         (3591, [1,2,4,5,13], [1,2,3,4,5,6])
        ]
labels = ['goods_id', 'properties_id_x', 'properties_id_y']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sales, columns=labels)

df
Out[4]:
goods_id    properties_id_x properties_id_y
0   3588    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  [1, 38, 9, 2, 18, 5]
1   3588    [2, 5, 7]   [1, 2, 4, 8, 14]
2   3588    [3, 10, 13] [1, 3, 4, 6, 12]
3   3588    [4, 5, 61]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 5]
4   3590    [3, 5, 6, 1, 21]    [3, 10, 13]
5   3590    [8, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9]  [2, 5, 7]
6   3591    [1, 2, 4, 5, 13]    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Having df of goods and their properties. Need to compare goods **properties_id_x** with **properties_id_y** row by row and return only those rows whose lists have both `"1"` and `"5"` in them. Cannot figure out how to do it.

**Desired output:**

```
0   3588    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  [1, 38, 9, 2, 18, 5]
6   3591    [1, 2, 4, 5, 13]    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
In [176]: mask  = df.apply(lambda r: {1,5} <= (set(r['properties_id_x']) & set(r['properties_id_y'])), axis=1)

In [177]: mask
Out[177]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
dtype: bool

In [178]: df[mask]
Out[178]:
   goods_id     properties_id_x       properties_id_y
0      3588  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  [1, 38, 9, 2, 18, 5]
6      3591    [1, 2, 4, 5, 13]    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [183]: mask = df.properties_id_x.map(lambda x: {1,5} <= set(x)) & df.properties_id_y.map(lambda x: {1,5} <= set(x))

In [184]: df[mask]
Out[184]:
   goods_id     properties_id_x       properties_id_y
0      3588  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  [1, 38, 9, 2, 18, 5]
6      3591    [1, 2, 4, 5, 13]    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well but it only with those 3 columns. In real case I have more than 3 columns and so I get error TypeError: ("'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 2683') . Is there a way to use your code with lots of columns?

Comment: @MaxU what is this doing `{1,5} <` ? I understand its following part is set intersection.

Comment: @IvanShelonik, do you have more than two columns containing lists? Do you want to check ALL of them?

Comment: @MaxU I have this structure 
""
goods_id             int64
pred_item            int64
Distance           float64
properties_id_x     object
properties_id_y     object
dtype: object
'''
In the case above there is a structure 
""
goods_id            int64
properties_id_x    object
properties_id_y    object
dtype: object
""

Comment: @YOLO, yeah, actually it should be [`<=` and it's a synonym for `issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: @MaxU All works fine, it was my mistake with NaN available in 2683 row as the second list. Thanks again)

Comment: @IvanShelonik, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `dict` intersection

```
df["intersect"] = df.apply(lambda x: set(x["properties_id_x"]).intersection(x["properties_id_y"]), axis=1)
df[df["intersect"].map(lambda x: (1 in x) and (5 in x))]

>> 0   3588    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  [1, 38, 9, 2, 18, 5]
>> 6   3591    [1, 2, 4, 5, 13]    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```